# Problemas de codificação

Tags: python, python-2.7, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, unicode

estou com problema de codage que não consigo resolver. Eu já tentei várias coisas sugeridas, mas nenhuma funciona:

**Script:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

line = ["Oi     tudo bem com você","eu  GOSTO de café", "esta  situação é  Terrível"]

def suppressions(line):

    #coding = sys.stdout.encoding
    #line_coding = line

    mails = ' '.join(line)
    mails = ' '.join(mails.lower().strip(' ').split()) #tirar os espaços multiplos
    #mails = ' '.join(line.encode(coding))

    return mails

print suppressions(line)
```

**output:**

> ['oi tudo bem com voc\xc3\xaa eu gosto de caf\xc3\xa9 esta situa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o \xc3\xa9 terr\xc3\xadvel']

**output desejado:**

> oi tudo bem com você
>
> eu gosto de café
>
> esta situação é terrível

Sei que se eu tirar os acentos (ou utilisar python 3) resolve, mas infelizmente não posso fazer nenhuma dessas duas coisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, como você usa o output um terminal do sistema, no caso de usar linux, pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') # aqui você seta a codificação

line = ["Oi     tudo bem com você","eu  GOSTO de café", "esta  situação é  Terrível"]

def suppressions(line):
    mails = ' '.join(line)
    mails = ' '.join(mails.lower().strip(' ').split())
    return mails

print suppressions(line)
```

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Você está usando Linux ou Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Pode tentar usar o .encode('utf-8')

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

line = ["Oi     tudo bem com você","eu  GOSTO de café", "esta  situação é  Terrível"]

def suppressions(line):
   mails = ' '.join(line.encode('utf-8'))
   mails = ' '.join(mails.lower().strip(' ').split())
   return mails

print suppressions(line)
```